# How to use twitteR to request >150k followers ids?

Tags: r, twitter

I would like to use [the `twitteR` package](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR) for R to get a the list of followers IDs of a user with more than 150k followers. Calling naïvely the `getFollowersIDs()` method of `user-class` breaks because it overloads the api request limit (Client Error (429)). Is there a way of circumventing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly take the number of followers by  "followersCount" field of the user-class. I'm not sure. Just try.

Comment: Doesn't help: I don't want the number of followers but the list of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it if your bound to using `R`.  I absolutely love the `twitteR` package, but recently, I have been shifting some of my code to `python` through the use of modules like `tweepy`.  By no means do I intend to suggest that one language is better than the other, but when going beyond simple tasks, I have found python to be a tad more robust.

Comment: Thanks, yes: I've just started considering the possibility of using python for this particular task. I just liked the idea of doing the whole process using R.